# Bloquear click derecho sobre mi página web

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Como puedo evitar que den click derecho sobre mi página web?

No se si esto se pueda realizar con css ó javascript ó jquery, he investigado y supuestamente con este código se bloquea el click derecho:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onkeydown="return false">
```

Pero me he dado cuenta que esto solo funciona sobre el menú de mi pagina web y lo que me interesa es que sea general que en ninguna parte se pueda dar click derecho.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/737043/12429790

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las teclas del teclado, cada una tiene un identificador. En teoría, este código debería funcionarte

```js
const app = document.getElementById('app');

window.onload = function() {
  document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
} 

app.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('click izquierdo')
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  Solo click Izquierdo
</div>
```

.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

> El clic derecho es un **menú contextual auxiliar** que provee una serie de
> características y funciones, muchas de ellas ajustadas a la
> [accesibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Accessibility) para usuarios de Internet.

Copiar una sección de una frase porque te parece interesante, guardar una imagen, inspeccionar propiedades de accesibilidad e incluso [VoiceOver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Screen_reader) y otros lectores de pantalla.

Por no hablar de que motores de búsqueda globales como Google, tienen este tipo de *snippets de conducta* (realmente lo llaman así) en cuenta, luego añadir esta función a tu sitio web solo disminuye el SEO e influye en los resultados de búsqueda.

**¿Necesitas deshabilitar la selección de texto?**

```css
foo {
 user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none
}
```

**¿No quieres que guarden tus imágenes?** Súbelas en baja calidad o agrega una *[watermark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watermark)*.

**¿No quieres que el código fuente de tu sitio web sea fácilmente accesible?** Esta no es la Internet que estás buscando.

**En definitiva:** deshabilitar el clic derecho cabrea a la gente y te hace parecer bastante arrogante, especialmente si añades la típica frase de *no tienes permiso para hacer clic derecho*.